# R: How should I specify the "init" and "fixed" parameters in the arima function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a problem in understanding how the `init` and `fixed` parameters are specified in the `arima` function in R.

For example, I will use R's built-in dataset `lh` to illustrate the idea:

The line below works fine

```
arima(lh, order = c(1,0,0))
```

But this line does not work as expected and generated the error message below:

```
arima(lh, order = c(1,0,0), init=c(0.17))

Error in arima(lh, order = c(1, 0, 0), init = c(0.17)) : 
'init' is of the wrong length
```

Since I am specifying an ARMA(1,0) model, `init` should only take one parameter. Then why is this not working ? What are the "model parameters" expected for `init` ? This is really confusing.

I encounter the same problem with the `fixed` parameters in `arima` as well. I believe they are actually the same problem. So, if one of them is solved, the other is also automatically solved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation carefully. `help(arima)` clearly tells you that `init` relates to the initial values of **parameters**:

> `init`     optional numeric vector of initial **parameter** values. Missing
>   values will be filled in, by zeroes except for regression
>   coefficients. Values already specified in fixed will be ignored.

Similarly, `fixed` also relates to **parameters**:

> `fixed`    optional numeric vector of the same length as the total number
>   of parameters. If supplied, only NA entries in fixed will be varied.
>   transform.pars = TRUE will be overridden (with a warning) if any AR
>   parameters are fixed. It may be wise to set transform.pars = FALSE
>   when fixing MA parameters, especially near non-invertibility.

Note that what you think you are passing as initial values Y<sub>0</sub>, Y<sub>-1</sub>, ... are taken from the actual values of the series itself.

---

Try calling `coef` on the return of

```
arima(lh, order = c(1,0,0))
```

to see how many parameters you are are likely to need to initialize.

Comment: I read the documentation before I posed the question. What I don't understand is what are the initial "parameters" the document is referring to ? For example, if i specify the `order=c(1,0,0)` in `arima`, I thought there is only one  parameter, which is just  `phi1` . But I got an error.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Try calling `coef` on the return object from `arima`. How many elements do you see?

Comment: O i see. So in the case of `order=c(1,0,0)`, the parameters are `ar1` and `intercept`. So, I was missing the `intercept` term all along. Am I correct?